# How to go about creating this design in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, calendar

Hi I proposed the design for a calendar app for my school, they accepted the design and now I need to create an android app that does what the design shows. Its basically a calendar app with events, these events are on an online calendar, and I would need to display them as shown, also when clicked on a specific day it would show the events for that day as well, where the event list is. I'm asking for suggestions for how to create this, I've looked at some android libraries but can't get any of them to work, the dependencies always give me an error.

[This is the design I mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZBaU.png)

Comment: `I've looked at some android libraries but can't get any of them to work, the dependencies always give me an error.`. Let's start by fixing the errors you get.

Comment: 1. This is off-topic. You should probably go look at some UI guides of some sort.     
2. You don't need extra dependencies to do this.                                                               3. Don't ask for suggestions on any SE site.